# NHibernate 3.2 elegant IoC of mapping by code

Tags: nhibernate, inversion-of-control

Now that I have a good handle on NHibernate 3.2 I now feel ready to use it in anger. What I need now is an ellegant way to inject the mappings I want from an IoC container like castle windsor or the like.

The project that I am working on requires 2 sets of mappings, one to a legacy database that needs to stay put for now and one to the new schema designed to replace the old database at some point in the future. Baring in mind that I am using mapping by code rather than xml mapping.

So at a controller/middle tier level you'd be injecting a repository that implements your `ISomethingRepository` interface and as a parameter into that repository somehow passing a collection of ClassMapping objects.

Any ideas about the best way to go about this would be appreciated. I'm interested in the general architecture which is why I'm not specifying an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a SessionFactoryFactory which consumes a ConfigurationGenerator.